# Add wordpress shortcode before element

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a block to all my posts, i am using the_content Hook to add the shortcode, the code below adds the shortcode after the specified element **$parags[3]** (the block shows after the fourth paragraphe), is there something i can do to change the order and put the shortcode before the specified element (the other way around)

```
add_filter('the_content', 'ak_the_content_filter', 10, 1);
function ak_the_content_filter($content)
{
    $parags = explode('</p>', $content);
    $parags[3] .= do_shortcode('[SHORTCODE HERE]');
    $content_new = '';

    foreach ($parags as $parag) {
        $content_new .= $parag;
    }

    return $content_new;
}
```

Comment: You can do this to put it before the parags[3], `$parags[3] = do_shortcode('[SHORTCODE HERE]') . $parags[3];`

But not sure to understand which element you want to be before

Comment: the code adds the shortcode after the foourth paragraphe of the content, i want the the opposite, i want to add the shortcode before the fourth paragraphe